# Android CameraX CameraView how to set video resolution?

Tags: android, android-camerax, android-video-record

I use CameraView from CameraX library, for recording video. But I can't find any settings of video recording process. Earlier I use old library version `1.0.0-alpha08` and default resolution(1920 х 1080) suited me, but that version had some issues. For now I'm using `1.0.0-beta02`, I get very strange resolution (1600 x 1200 - Pixel 3a 1400x1200 - Huawei p20 lite).

Answer (score 1):

You can configure recorder's quality using [QualitySelector](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/video/QualitySelector)

```kotlin
val preferredQuality = Quality.HD
val recorder = Recorder.Builder()
    .setQualitySelector(
        QualitySelector.from(
            preferredQuality,
            FallbackStrategy.higherQualityOrLowerThan(preferredQuality)
        )
    )
    .build()
val videoCapture = VideoCapture.withOutput(recorder)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 val imageCaptureConfig = ImageCaptureConfig.Builder()
    .setLensFacing(CameraX.LensFacing.BACK)
    .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CaptureMode.MAX_QUALITY)
    .setTargetResolution(Size(width, height))
    .setTargetAspectRatio(Rational(3,4))
    .build()
```

replace width and height with your dimens.
3,4 in 'Rational(3,4)' with your ratio (you can also remove it)

Comment: If I change the resolution/ lens facing on click of different Buttons, do I need to call the initCamera method again? Any other way to change it dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

In version [1.0.0-beta06](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/camera#camera-core-1.0.0-beta06) you can use **`setTargetResolution(resolution: Size)`** or `setMaxResolution(resolution: Size)` in `VideoCaptureConfig.Builder()` used for video UseCase.

```
videoCapture = VideoCaptureConfig.Builder()
    .setTargetResolution(VIDEO_SIZE)
    .setMaxResolution(VIDEO_SIZE)
    .build()
```

Comment: `VideoCaptureConfig.Builder()` does not exist in  `1.0.0-beta10`

Comment: If I change the resolution on click of different Buttons, do I need to call the initCamera method again? Any other way to change it dynamically?